Syntax error in Crystal Reports 11.5 formula
I found this fomrula in one report, that apparently worked in CR 8.0, but when i did the conversion to the new version of CR (11.5) it stopped workig.
The formula is the one below, and the errore occured is: "Missing )." and the program highlights ExecSQL
enter image description here
If I comment that line the formula doesn't retunr any other error.
I tried different ways of adding or removing the missing parentesis, but I couldn't make it work.
I found an other way to solve my problem, but I'm curious of the correct way to use it as it was written and to know where the missing parentesis should be
When doing this, the error changes in: "it is expected a number, a currency amount, a Boolean value, a date, date-time, or a string"
Thank you in advance for help :)

ExecSQL is not a standard Crystal Reports function. It comes from an extra User Function Library (UFL).
You would need to purchase/install the UFL in order to allow that expression to be recognized as valid.
